# Optimize iteration through large number of characters in a string

Tags: python

How can I optimize iteration through large number of characters in a string ? Imagine situation:

```
a = []
b = []
for char in characters:   # characters are string of 300 different characters (integers and letters)
    if char.isalpha() and char.islower():
        a.append(char)
    else:
        b.append(char)
```

How can I speed up execution if there are 300 characters (integers and letters) in `characters` ?
I tried to use `a = ''` and `a += char` but as turned out using list is faster when I timed it.

This is the code I came up with. It works but it's too slow:

```
def scramble(s1, s2):
    for char in s2:
        if char not in s1:
            return False
    s2_chars, s1_chars = [], []
    duplicate_chars_s2 = []
    duplicate_chars_s1 = []
    found_all_duplicates = True
    for char in s2:
        if char in s2_chars:
            duplicate_chars_s2.append(char)
        s2_chars.append(char)
    for char in s1:
        if char in s1_chars:
            duplicate_chars_s1.append(char)
        s1_chars.append(char)

    for char in duplicate_chars_s2:
        if char not in duplicate_chars_s1:
            found_all_duplicates = False
    return True if found_all_duplicates else False
```

Now try to run the function when `s1` and `s2` are 300 long string of characters.

The purpose of the function is to determine whether or not characters in `s1` can build string in `s2`. Meaning ... I need a code that counts duplicate characters and determines if there are enough duplicates in `s1` to build the desired string.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205763/discussion-on-question-by-mr-incredible-optimize-iteration-through-large-number).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another faster solution, got it accepted in 11.x seconds. The normal `Counter` solution shown by @chepner gets accepted in about 1 second less.

```
def scramble(s1, s2):
    it = iter(sorted(s1))
    return all(c in it for c in sorted(s2))
```

Here's the problem, btw: https://www.codewars.com/kata/55c04b4cc56a697bb0000048/train/python

Comment: You're on CodeWars too. Nice.

Comment: I think I'm gonna leave this as I don't trust the tests anymore.

Comment: @mr_incredible Well like I said, I got it accepted in 11.x seconds, so it's close to the 12 seconds limit. Times vary, so just try to submit it a few times.

Comment: I believe you. It blows my mind that my solution took up 19 lines of code and you had the same result with 3 lines of code.

Comment: You should be my mentor.  :)

Comment: Yes, I had to look up what `iter()` and `all()` functions do in the docs as I never used them before.

Comment: I was doing it the long long winded way.

Comment: Your code passed on my end just now. Including the performance tests.

Answer (score 2):

`in` operation in a list can be expensive. You should use `set` instead of `list` if you have a lot of `in` operations. You can read more about `set`s in [the python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset). In short, the lookup time is O(1) in `set` compared to O(n) in `list`.

Also [Python docs](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Avoiding_dots...) say that dots are expensive because this has to be reevaluated for every iteration. You can get rid of them using this:

```
a = []
a_append = a.append

a_append('string')
```

This will make adding to the list faster. Then you can convert it to a set and do the `in` operations and then you should be good to go.

Comment: Characters counts are significant; while you may be able to use a `set` somehow, it's not a drop-in replacement for a `list` in this context.

Comment: I think set and set.add can be used if it's just to check if something exists in a set of something else.
if the number of chars is relevant, (s)he can use a dict with key as the char and value as the number of time it occurs.

The main point being - `list` is not the best option to perform `in` operations on.

Comment: It doesn't help to point that out if you don't have a *workable* alternative to suggest. Otherwise, you just have a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the code shown is the bottleneck (which I doubt, but let's go with it), the most expensive thing you can do anything about is the repeated attribute lookups.

```
a = []
b = []

# Cache the bound methods
add_to_a = a.append
add_to_b = b.append

# Cache the unbound methods
is_alpha = str.isalpha
is_lower = str.islower

for char in characters:
    if is_alpha(char) and is_lower(char):
        add_to_a(char)
    else:
        add_to_b(char)
```

In a test involving 300 randomly chosen characters from `string.ascii_lowercase`, `string.ascii_uppercase`, `string.digits`, and `string.punctuation`, the above took 35 microseconds, compared to 54 microseconds for the original code.

I would write your `scramble`, though, as follows:

```
from collections import Counter


def scramble(s1, s2):
    c1 = Counter(s1)
    c2 = Counter(s2)

    return all(c2[c] <= c1[c] for c in s2)
```

You can build `s2` from the characters in `s1` as long as every character in `s2` appears in `c1` at least as many times as it appears in `c2`. `Counter`, being implemented in C, should be able to compute the character counts far faster than any equivalent Python code.

Comment: I haven't considered `Counter` from the `collections` library. Will give it a try.

Comment: What's the time if you do `pass` instead of the `append`s? Or if you just do `is_alpha(char) and is_lower(char)` in the loop?

Comment: @chepner  What's the index `x` in your example ?

Comment: @mr_incredible A typo for `c` :/

Comment: @chepner  Believe or not but despite your code being 5x shorter than mine but still timed out ! But like I said to others it looks like the tests can't be trusted.

Comment: What exactly is imposing the time constraint? What is the *exact* call to scramble that times out?

Comment: It's a Pytest on CodeWars. I can see only the basic tests but I don't get to see the other tests. The platform says it allows only 12 seconds for the code to finish executing.

Comment: They don't show the contents of the performance tests, they're just described as "Testing for two strings up to 600000 characters".

Comment: List comprehension is faster than loop+append, so it *might* be faster to do two list comprehensions or to do one with a side effect on the other: `a = [c for c in characters if is_alpha(c) and is_lower(c) or add_to_b(c)]`. Can you benchmark that as well?

Comment: A list comprehension uses append internally. I'm not interesting in further shaving of microseconds off the runtime of otherwise identical code. The `Counter` solution accurately reflects what `scramble` is supposed to do and is fast enough.

Comment: @chepner It's a lower level append, though. LIST_APPEND instead of LOAD_NAME+CALL_FUNCTION. Compare `dis.dis('[x for x in X]')` and `dis.dis('for x in X: append(x)')`.

Answer (score 1):

**Benchmarks** of three solutions on my PC (and some IMHO interesting **analysis**):

```
scramble1 0.235 seconds
scramble2 0.232 seconds
scramble3 0.054 seconds
```

[Their](https://www.codewars.com/kata/55c04b4cc56a697bb0000048/train/python) "Performance tests" are ten tests described only as *"Testing for two strings up to 600000 characters"*, and the problem text says *"Only lower case letters will be used (a-z)"*. So in my benchmark I made `s1` a string of 600,000 random letters from a-z, and made `s2` a random permutation of it. That's as hard as it gets.

Now... all three solutions, when submitted there, get accepted in around 10-12 seconds (not always, due to runtime variation). Why isn't the third solution much faster there? I have a suspicion. As mentioned in the discussions there, Python 2 solutions don't work because *the judge* crashes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 51, in <module>
    do_test()
  File "main.py", line 17, in do_test
    from random import randint, choices, shuffle
ImportError: cannot import name 'choices'
```

So I guess their judge uses `choices` and `shuffle` similar to how I do. Let's measure that:

```
t0 = time.perf_counter()
s1 = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=600_000))
a2 = list(s1)
random.shuffle(a2)
s2 = ''.join(a2)
t1 = time.perf_counter()
print(t1 - t0)
```

Took about 0.65 seconds. Much more than the 0.05 to 0.24 seconds the solutions need! Thus I suspect the total time includes the judge's time to *generate* the inputs, and it's by far the majority of the total time.

Benchmark code:

```
import string
import random
from timeit import timeit

from collections import Counter
def scramble1(s1, s2):
    c1 = Counter(s1)
    c2 = Counter(s2)
    return all(c2[c] <= c1[c] for c in s2)

def scramble2(s1, s2):
    it = iter(sorted(s1))
    return all(c in it for c in sorted(s2))

def scramble3(s1, s2):
    return all(s1.count(c) >= s2.count(c) for c in set(s2))

# Generate hardest test case
s1 = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=600_000))
a2 = list(s1)
random.shuffle(a2)
s2 = ''.join(a2)

# Run the benchmarks
for _ in range(3):
    for scramble in scramble1, scramble2, scramble3:
        seconds = timeit(lambda: scramble(s1, s2), number=1)
        print(scramble.__name__, '%.3f' % seconds, 'seconds')
    print()
```

One more thing: The by far fastest solution is the one that goes over each string 26 times. How can it be 4.6 times *faster* when it does 26 times *more* work?!? Well, that's because searching for a single character in a string is unbelievably fast. I measured that a while ago (though I think it was `index`, not `count`) and found that it checked 5 billion characters per second. Yes, **b**illion! What was even more shocking was that it was on a 4 GHz CPU! How can it check more than one character per CPU cycle?!? I checked the source code and if I remember correctly, it internally uses C's `memchr` which in turn uses some multibyte CPU instruction that checks multiple bytes at the same time.